# Problema con menu vertical css y html5

Tags: html5, css3

les paso a comentar, hice un menú vertical, funciona re bien, el problema es que es fixed, cosa que si quiero, pero cuando los elementos sobre pasan el alto, desaparecen. Se que esta el overflow scroll, pero pasa que tengo otro botón para abrir el menú que no lo puedo sacar, y si coloco scroll se me va, osea, necesito que el menú haga scroll sin perder el botón ni el fixed del menu. Me explico?. Acá esta el html

```
 <div class="menuModulos" id="menuModulo">

  <button onclick="AbrirMenu();" class="btn btn-success BotonAbrirMenu">Módulos</button>
  <ul class="text-center">
      {{#each Modulos}}
      <li class="mt-5">

          <button onclick="MostrarTemas({{idModuloXCurso}}, this)" id="{{idModuloXCurso}}"
              class="btnModulo btn btn-sm btn-success">{{NombreModulo}}</button>

      </li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

y este es el css

```
.menuModulos{
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 10rem;
background-color: black;
z-index: 1000;
left: -10rem;


}

.menuModulos li{

list-style: none;
margin-left:-3rem;
}

.menuModulos ul{
position: relative;
margin-top: 10%;
overflow-y: visible;
}

.menuModulos .BotonAbrirMenu{
position: absolute !important;
height: 2rem !important;
width: 10rem !important;
margin-left: 60% !important;
margin-top: 20rem !important;
transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Espero puedan darme una mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione, aca dejo la solucion que encontre por si alguien tiene esta misma duda.

```
.menuModulos{
position: fixed;
height:95%;
width: 8rem;
background-color: black;
z-index: 1000;
left: -8rem;
overflow: scroll;


}

/* ACA ESCONDO EL SCROLL ORIGINADO POR EL OVERFLOW DE .menuModulos */

.menuModulos::-webkit-scrollbar{
width: 0px;
}
```

Espero a alguien le sirva.